# iPad app crashed due to memory warning while combining/merging two images

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiimageview, uiimage

My app is crashing due to heavy use of memory while I am doing image processing.

Basically my whole app depends on following method in which logic for combining images are used another method i used for loading images from bundle.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImages:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        UIImage *image = nil;

        CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
        if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        }
        else
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
        }

        [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))];

        firstImage =nil;
        [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))];


        secondImage=nil;

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
}

- (UIImage*) getImage:(NSString*)imagename
{
    NSString *fileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagename];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    return image;
}
```

the above methods are called from following method numerous times

```
- (void) applyMaterialWithValue:(NSDictionary*)dict
{

    @synchronized(self)
    {

        NSString *materialName = [dict valueForKey:@"material"];
        NSString *optionName = [dict valueForKey:@"option"];
        //NSString *preset_Name = [dict valueForKey:@"preset"];
        NSString *name = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
        if([[GlobalIntVariable getCMFScheme] isEqualToString:@"preset1"])

        {
            if(!isMetalPressed)
            {

                [GlobalIntVariable setCurrentMaterialName:@"Preset 1 Metal Plating"];
            }
            if(!isLeatherPressed)
            {
                [GlobalIntVariable setCurrentPresetName:@"preset1"];

            }

        }
        if([[GlobalIntVariable getCMFScheme] isEqualToString:@"preset2"])

        {

            if(!isMetalPressed)
            {

                [GlobalIntVariable setCurrentMaterialName:@"Preset 2 Metal Plating"];
            }
            if(!isLeatherPressed)
            {
                [GlobalIntVariable setCurrentPresetName:@"preset2"];

            }

        }

        if ([materialName isEqualToString:AREAD4METALCOMPONENET ]|| [materialName isEqualToString:AREA8METALCOMPONENET])
        {
            [GlobalIntVariable setCurrentMaterialName:name];
        }


        if([optionName isEqualToString:OPTION0])
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {

                UIImage *presetImg1L1Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image1L1Standard"]];
                imgView1Layout1Standard.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout1Standard.image withImage:presetImg1L1Standard];
                imgView1Layout1StandardPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout1StandardPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg1L1Standard];
                 presetImg1L1Standard=nil;



                UIImage *presetImg1L1Premium = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image1L1Premium"]];
                imgView1Layout1Premium.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout1Premium.image withImage:presetImg1L1Premium];
                imgView1Layout1PremiumPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout1PremiumPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg1L1Premium];
                presetImg1L1Premium=nil;

                UIImage *presetImg1L2Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image1L2Standard"]];
                imgView1Layout2Standard.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout2Standard.image withImage:presetImg1L2Standard];
                imgView1Layout2StandardPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout2StandardPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg1L2Standard];
                presetImg1L2Standard=nil;

                UIImage *presetImg1L2Premium = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image1L2Premium"]];
                imgView1Layout2Premium.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout2Premium.image withImage:presetImg1L2Premium];
                imgView1Layout2PremiumPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout2PremiumPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg1L2Premium];
                presetImg1L2Premium=nil;

            }

            @autoreleasepool
            {

                UIImage *presetImg2L1Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image2L1Standard"]];
                imgView2Layout1Standard.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Layout1Standard.image withImage:presetImg2L1Standard];
                imgView2Layout1StandardPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Layout1StandardPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg2L1Standard];
                presetImg2L1Standard=nil;

                UIImage *presetImg2L1Premium = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image2L1Premium"]];
                imgView2Layout1Premium.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Layout1Premium.image withImage:presetImg2L1Premium];
                imgView2Layout1PremiumPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Layout1PremiumPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg2L1Premium];
                presetImg2L1Premium=nil;

                UIImage *presetImg2L2Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image2L2Standard"]];
                imgView2Layout2Standard.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Layout2Standard.image withImage:presetImg2L2Standard];
                imgView2Layout2StandardPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Layout2StandardPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg2L2Standard];
                presetImg2L2Standard=nil;

                UIImage *presetImg2L2Premium = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image2L2Premium"]];
                imgView2Layout2Premium.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Layout2Premium.image withImage:presetImg2L2Premium];
                imgView2Layout2PremiumPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Layout2PremiumPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg2L2Premium];
                presetImg2L2Premium=nil;


            }

            @autoreleasepool
            {

                UIImage *presetImg3L1Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image3L1Standard"]];
                imgView3Layout1Standard.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Layout1Standard.image withImage:presetImg3L1Standard];
                imgView3Layout1StandardPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Layout1StandardPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg3L1Standard];
                presetImg3L1Standard=nil;

                UIImage *presetImg3L1Premium = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image3L1Premium"]];
                imgView3Layout1Premium.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Layout1Premium.image withImage:presetImg3L1Premium];
                imgView3Layout1PremiumPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Layout1PremiumPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg3L1Premium];
                presetImg3L1Premium=nil;

                UIImage *presetImg3L2Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image3L2Standard"]];
                imgView3Layout2Standard.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Layout2Standard.image withImage:presetImg3L2Standard];
                imgView3Layout2StandardPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Layout2StandardPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg3L2Standard];
                presetImg3L2Standard=nil;


                UIImage *presetImg3L2Premium = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image3L2Premium"]];
                imgView3Layout2Premium.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Layout2Premium.image withImage:presetImg3L2Premium];
                imgView3Layout2PremiumPSUOn.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Layout2PremiumPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg3L2Premium];
                presetImg3L2Premium=nil;

            }



        }

        @autoreleasepool
        {
            UIImage *presetImg4Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image4Standard"]];
            mainImageView4.image=[ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:mainImageView4.image withImage:presetImg4Standard];
            presetImg4Standard=nil;

            UIImage *presetImg5Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image5Standard"]];
            mainImageView5.image=[ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:mainImageView5.image withImage:presetImg5Standard];
             presetImg5Standard=nil;
        }

        @autoreleasepool
        {
            UIImage *presetImg1Detail1 = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image1DetailView1"]];
            imgView1Detail.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Detail.image withImage:presetImg1Detail1];
             presetImg1Detail1=nil;

            UIImage *presetImg2Detail2 = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image2DetailView2"]];
            imgView2Detail.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView2Detail.image withImage:presetImg2Detail2];
            presetImg2Detail2=nil;

             UIImage *presetImg3Detail3 = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:@"image3DetailView3"]];
            imgView3Detail.image = [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView3Detail.image withImage:presetImg3Detail3];
            presetImg3Detail3=nil;

        }


        [self setMaterialReflection];

        NSString *strShowIndicator = [dict valueForKey:@"hideIndicator"];
        if ([strShowIndicator isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
            [appDelegate hideIndicator];
        }



    }
}
```

the issue is this when above method called the memory usage goes beyond 400 mb & i receive 2 - 3 times received memory warning message in console & my app is crashed after that.

in runtime when above method in execution memory always increasing even as you see in above method i have nil all the uiimage objects & also used @autorelese block but memory is not releasing.

i want to decrease memory after each call of following method.

> - (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImages:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage

in above method i am combining two images in to one image & all images in my projects are of average size of 2 MB.

i have decreased size of images to 2 mb average before it was of 4 mb, if i reduce images resolution than quality of app is decreasing & that is not what i want.

i have done a google about it & tried to find solution on stack overflow also but still got nothing, so please guide me through this issue.

please suggest me how can i improve method of image combining ? & how can i optimize above methods ?,so that memory usage can be reduced & my app can run smoothly.

Comment: You said that you had memory-leaks (cf. tag), but what line exactly is causing memory leak? What does say Instruments?

Comment: How big are the images _in pixels_? That they are stored (as JPEGs, PNGs?) at a size of 2 MB doesn't mean that they take up 2 MB when in memory...

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can suggest is don't draw each and every time to capture the image from graphic context.

Try the following steps:

1. Pass the dictionary to the method imageByCombiningImages:
2. Calculate the frame
3. Iterate all the images from dictionary and draw
4. Capture the final image only once.

Edit 1:

Edited Method:

```
    + (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImages:(NSDictionary *)imageDict
    {
     UIImage *image = nil;

            CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeZero;
    NSArray *allImages = [imageDict allValues];
    for (UIImage *image in allImages) {
    newImageSize  = CGSizeMake(MAX(image.size.width, newImageSize.size.width), MAX(image.size.height, newImageSize.size.height));
    }


            if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
            {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
            }
            else
            {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
            }

    for (UIImage *image in allImages) {
            [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-image.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-image.size.height)/2))];
    }

image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;

    }
```

Edit 2:

when you create image using **UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()**, internally  **cg raster data** is created by the core graphics to create the bitmap image. it will consume more memory.

you can avoid memory warning by delaying sequential method calls to merge the image.

Edit 3:

Modified image merge method:

```
- (void)imageByCombiningImages:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage
{

        UIImage *image = nil;

        CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
        if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        }
        else
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
        }

        [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))];

        firstImage =nil;
        [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))];


        secondImage=nil;

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self performSelector:@selector(merge:) withObject:image afterDelay:1]; // modify the delay which will work out for you

}
```

Add all the image keys in array and call the method,

```
- (void)merge:(UIImage *)image {

    switch (rowIndex) {
        case 0: {
            UIImage *presetImg1L1Standard = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex]]];
            switch (sectionIndex) {
                case 0:
                    [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout1Standard.image withImage:presetImg1L1Standard];
                    sectionIndex++;
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    imgView1Layout1Standard.image = image;
                    [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout1StandardPSUOn.image withImage:presetImg1L1Standard];
                    rowIndex ++;
                    sectionIndex = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
            break;
        case 1: {
            UIImage *image = [APP_DEL getImage:[dict valueForKey:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex]]];
            switch (sectionIndex) {
                case 0:
                    imgView1Layout1StandardPSUOn.image = image;
                    [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout1Premium.image withImage:image];
                    sectionIndex++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    imgView1Layout1Premium.image = image;
                    [ImageOperations imageByCombiningImages:imgView1Layout1Premium.image withImage:presetImg1L1Premium];
                    rowIndex ++;
                    sectionIndex = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                        break;
                }
            }
                break;
// ................. and so on
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...but i am not understanding what you are trying to say...can you edit my imageByCombiningImages: method? so that i can try that in my code

Comment: @PRJ feel free if you want more help for the Edit 2 approach. I will help you with code snippet...

Comment: but that is the last solution i have, can you give some suggestion how to improve applyMaterialWithValue: method?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do the calculations on GPU, for instance using one of [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)'s [blend filters](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#blending-modes).