# combine two images and get one image but app crashed due to memory pressure

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, ios7, uiimageview, mask

My app is crashed due to memory pressure.

In my app, I have combine two images and get one image and set this image in UIImageView using this code.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImages:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        UIImage *image = nil;

        CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
        if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        }
        else
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
        }

        [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))];

        firstImage =nil;
        [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))];


        secondImage=nil;

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
}
```

I have call this function 5 times at a time and set UIImageView as per return image from this function.

But at the time of execution memory always increase and after some time app is going to be crashed.

so, tell me how to decrease the memory pressure ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might come from something else. I just run instruments on your function and it all seams to work ok.

The spikes are when I click a button which runs your code. 
[image]

This is the code:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImages:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        UIImage *image = nil;

        CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
        if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        }
        else
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
        }

        [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))];

        firstImage =nil;
        [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2), roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))];


        secondImage=nil;

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
}

- (IBAction)callFunctionAction:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *firstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
    UIImage *secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];

    UIImage *thirdImage = [[self class] imageByCombiningImages:firstImage withImage:secondImage];
    self.imageView.image = thirdImage;
}
```

The last line will throw a warning but the example still works.

Comment: But I have call this function 5 to 6 times, and set this image in UIImageView. and I have used images with 2 MB size and resolution 1024*768 and also retina images for retina iPad.

Comment: I just added an UIImageView to the story board and the edited the IBAction to set the image of the image view like this: self.imageView.image = thirdImage; Instruments returns the same thing. The problem is probably somewhere else

Comment: please see this.. I am using this method like this ......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130335/ipad-app-crashed-due-to-memory-warning-while-combining-merging-two-images

Comment: Did you test my code with instruments? Are you sure this is the part of code that is causing the memory problems?